# In Python, how do I remove the "root" tag in an HTML snippet?

Tags: python, html

Suppose I have an HTML snippet like this:

```
<div>
  Hello <strong>There</strong>
  <div>I think <em>I am</em> feeing better!</div>
  <div>Don't you?</div>
  Yup!
</div>
```

What's the best/most robust way to remove the surrounding root  element, so it looks like this:

```
Hello <strong>There</strong>
<div>I think <em>I am</em> feeing better!</div>
<div>Don't you?</div>
Yup!
```

I've tried using lxml.html like this:

lxml.html.fromstring(fragment_string).drop_tag()

But that only gives me "Hello", which I guess makes sense.  Any better ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit odd in lxml (or ElementTree).  You'd have to do:

```
def inner_html(el):
    return (el.text or '') + ''.join(tostring(child) for child in el)
```

Note that lxml (and ElementTree) have no special way to represent a document except rooted with a single element, but `.drop_tag()` would work like you want if that `<div>` wasn't the root element.

Comment: That works great; thanks!  Just to complete this:

def remove_root(html):
  parsed = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
  return (parsed.text or '') + ''.join([lxml.html.tostring(child) for child in parsed])

Answer (score 1):

You can use **BeautifulSoup** package. For this particular html I would go like this:

```
import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div>
  Hello <strong>There</strong>
  <div>I think <em>I am</em> feeing better!</div>
  <div>Don't you?</div>
  Yup!
</div>"""

bs = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(html)

no_root = '\n'.join(map(unicode, bs.div.contents))
```

BeautifulSoup has many nice features that will allow you to tweak this example for many other cases. Full documentation: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html.

Answer (score 0):

For such a simple task you can use regexp like
`r'<(.*?)>(.*)</\1>'` and get match #2 (\2 in perl terms) from it

You should also put flags like `ms` for correct multi-line working

Comment: If you trust it is properly formed you could do `xml.split('>', 1)[1].rsplit('<', 1)[0]`